# I can't find a route to my elasticsearch ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, kibana

I am working on a .net project and i want to edit (in this case a superhero) name. the code i have in my edit backend is this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")).DefaultIndex("superheroes");
            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
            var superhero = client.Get<esHero>(new DocumentPath<esHero>(Request.QueryString["id"]).Index("superheroes"));

            LitID.Text = superhero.Source.Id;
            LitName.Text = superhero.Source.name;
            LitPowers.Text = superhero.Source.powerstats;
            LitOccupation.Text = superhero.Source.occupation;

         }

    }
```

and on the line var superhero =.. is throwing an exception saying : 'No route taking 1 parameters{index}/_doc/{id}'

i am using elastic search 7.6.2 and nest 7.6.2
i am unsure what the issue is with this because i can load them in my default page.

This is in my kibana

```
    PUT superheroes
    {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "powerstats": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "occupation": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is how i added to the superhero database

```
POST superheroes/_doc/1
{
  "Id": "one",
  "name": "Superman",
  "powerstats": "Super strength, flight, invulnerability",
  "occupation": "No occupation"
}
```

in my code, my esHero class is like this:

```
public class esHero
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string powerstats { get; set; }
        public string occupation { get; set; }


    }
```

and my edit frontend looks like this  so far
(dont know if its related or anything)

```
<div>
             <asp:Literal ID="LitID" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <asp:Literal ID="LitName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <asp:Literal ID="LitPowers" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <asp:Literal ID="LitOccupation" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <asp:Literal ID="litInfo" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </div>
```

i tried searching elsewhere but i cant seem to find a way to fix this issue i have, can anyone help me?

Comment: Connection is probably not completing.  Is server expecting HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: how do i check that? @jdweng

Comment: If a connection completes you should get back a response with either 200 ok or a 400/500 error.  If connection does complete you will not get any response.  The error is than a time out.  You can also debug the server code and check if the connection completes.